# Seaborn overlap columns

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn, bar-chart, overlap

I would like to obtain an overlay of the columns, change their width and the distance between them. A bit like you could do in Excel. Is there a possibility?

```
plt.figure(figsize=[19*cm,6*cm], dpi=300)
sns.set_style("white")
g = sns.FacetGrid(g_grav_brick, col= "WALL CODE" )

g.map_dataframe(sns.barplot, x = "SAMPLE POSITION", y = "WATER MASS",
                                  hue= "SAMPLE DATE", palette = "OrRd",
                                  linewidth=1, dodge=(True),
                                  edgecolor="black")
```

Here is an example of what I would like to achieve:
[image]

Here's what I'm getting instead:
[image]

Comment: You could change the widths after the bars are created. See e.g. [how to set width on seaborn barplot](how to set width on seaborn barplot).  As a side note, `sns.FacetGrid` is a figure-level function that creates its own figure (`height=` sets the height of a single subplot, `aspect=` will define the widths).  You should remove `plt.figure()` here, as it is responsible for an empty figure.